# JQuery Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

my site is getting the error in this title in the javascript console.   Google seems to say that it is because jquery isn't loaded, but it is definitely visible in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://www.mjfreeway.com/naturalremedies/mml-connect/45.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("products").each(function() {
          $(this).find("product").each(function() {
            $("#output").append($(this).find("title").text() + "<br />");
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

the site is medical marijuana related, so nsfw for some.sorry for the messy head, it's in dev mode.
http://www.kindreviews.com/1/mmc/

Thanks,
zeem

Comment: you should probably post some code...

Comment: @Patrick: I agree, the problem is, what code. It's a big combination of pieces. :-)

Comment: You can see the code in the site linked above (this one: http://www.kindreviews.com/1/mmc/)

Comment: @zeemy23: This sort of problem is a matter of: Reduce, reduce, reduce until the problem goes away, and then look at the last thing you removed, add things back, etc. The good news is that the problem is reliable. The classic reason for this error is including a script using jQuery *before* including jQuery. My quick check didn't immediately show that that was what you were doing, but that page has a *lot* going on, so...

Comment: the code pulling the error is line 315

Comment: @brandizzi: Yes, but StackOverflow is meant to stand alone and endure; it's not just for solving @zeemy23's problem, but to be a reference for people encountering the same problems in the future to find. External links can get moved, get deleted, get modified... Also, ideally, people shouldn't have to follow a blind link in order to help. Tricky in this case, with this class of problem.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Apparently you are using both jQuery and Mootools and both of them do use `$` as an alias to a core function. Probably the `$` function which is generating this error is the Mootools function. I'd suggest you to try to write your jQuery code using `jQuery` instead of `$` so you can confirm my point is right or not.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help.  Removing mootools led to this error now: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: was fixed with tbthorpe's answer, but still problem, see his comments.

Comment: @zeemy23: You don't have to remove MooTools, you just have to make your code use the correct symbol for jQuery. If you use Chrome, put it in ["break on all exceptions" mode](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html#js_exceptions) and skip the first one (a 404 on one of your CSS files) and you'll see `$.noConflict();` followed by `$(document).ready(...`. On that second line, `$` no longer references jQuery, because that's what `noConflict` does, return teh symbol to its previous meaning (MooTools, in this case). Use `jQuery(document).ready(...` instead.

Comment: You should replace `$` for `jQuery` in ALL jQuery code, not only in the original error line. I've noted the script has an `$.ajax` just unther the `jQuery(document)` line. It should be `jQuery.ajax` instead (and `jQuery(xml)`, `jQuery(this)` and so on). HTH

Answer (score 8):

Yup - I believe that's exactly the problem.  jQuery and mooTools fight over the use of the $ notation.

You're on the right track with using

```
try{
   jQuery.noConflict();
 } catch(e){};
```

But after you use that, in order to use jQuery functionality, you have to call it jQuery(...) instead of $(...).  Example:

```
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("div").hide();
 });
```

Here's a link to the jQuery docs regarding this: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: thanks! your recommend worked, but now i'm getting a "Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined"  is it because the $ sign is in front of that as well?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the $ when you're using jQuery functionality.  In fact, it will break if you do.  Just replace the '$' with 'jQuery', and I believe it should work out for you.

Comment: you can also use: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
/* code with $ here */  
});`  and that will define $ for that local function scope only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I forgot to add the header-line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js">   
</script>
```