# Calling JavaScript function for HTML link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery so that when the user clicks on an HTML link, a function that I write in the JavaScript file is called.

```
<a href="#" id="advanced_options">Show advanced options</a>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#advanced_options").click(function() {
    alert('hello');
  });

});
```

When I click on the link, it doesn't alert, but instead jump to another link. Why is that?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery? Check your JS console.

Comment: Yes, my console says I'm loading jQuery.

Comment: If you don't want the link to link to the top of the page, then don't say `href="#"`. If you want a button that just does something with JS, and don't want to link to anything, then use an actual button and not a link.

Comment: In my console, on `$(document).ready(function()` it says `Uncaught Type Error: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`. But `jquery.min.js` is clearly loaded. What's going on?

Comment: By the way, JQuery is loaded from: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Found the solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706093/jquery-error-uncaught-typeerror-object-htmldocument-has-no-method-ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must prevent default browser behaviour:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#advanced_options").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading the link via an ajax query, so it's not on the page during the initial loading of the page use the jQuery on function: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on( 'click' , "#advanced_options" , function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
  });

});
```