# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

So I'm using a form to upload files, and trying to add a client validation for the size of the upload.

Form Element:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file">
```

JS:

```
$('#uploaded_file').bind('change', function() {
alert('This file size is: ' + this.files[0].size/1024/1024 + "MB");
});
```

It seems like it should be pretty straight forward... but I'm not good at JS, and get the 'null' action error above.

Comment: Are you sure you loaded jQuery correctly?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777062/jquery-field-is-null

Comment: Is the form element loaded on the page via javascript or is it already in the HTML source? That error looks like it can't find `$('#uploaded_file')`

Comment: I have other jquery running just fine, I just don't know if I'm running a version that supports all the functions?

Comment: place your code in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) .

Comment: No, it looks like `$` is not jQuery.

Comment: @Will The form is loaded from a PHP file and the JS is loaded by the footer, along with all other JS.

Comment: @TusharGupta When I do that I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' "

Comment: I am using MooTools... I think this might be the issue.

Comment: It's definitely a problem of jquery not correctly loaded. Could you show us the complete html code ?

Comment: Fixed! I was running MooTools, and wrapping the code above in a `(document).ready`revealed another error showing the conflict.

Followed these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706093/jquery-error-uncaught-typeerror-object-htmldocument-has-no-method-ready

New JS:

    jQuery('#uploaded_file').bind('change', function() {
    alert('This file size is: ' + this.files[0].size/1024/1024 + "MB");
    });

Works just fine! Thank you everyone for your help!